# jhipster- the meaning of entity action?

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I am new with JHipster. i am trying to find out following piece of code , really not getting it

```
data-translate="entity.action.edit"
```

where i can find entity.action.word ?

I am trying to add an button function . really confused . please help me out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are keys that refer to entries in the i18n JSON files. `entity.action.edit` is in the `global.json` file for each language you have installed, and looks something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "entity": {
        "action": {
            ...
            "edit": "Edit"
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```